# Overlay contour plots to visualize two different distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, contour

I am trying to visualize how data from two different processes differ using plotly `histogram2dcontour` plot. Right now I am producing these these plots separately.

Plot1 represents the distribution of data from process 1

[image]

Plot2 represents the distribution of data from process 2
[image]

Is there anyway I can overlay these plots on top of each other and look at them simultaneously in one plot rather looking at them as two different plot? Any advise is much appreciated.

Below is the [link](http://www.readsy.co/spritzy/test_df.txt) to the reproducible dataset which I am using to generate these separate plots.

http://www.readsy.co/spritzy/test_df.txt

Comment: @G5W, I am trying to overlay these plots on top of each other,

Comment: Can you add the code you are currently using? Otherwise I am afraid this question will be closed soon.